# Android Updating Text_Widget from another Thread

Tags: android, android-activity, android-thread

I have little loading screen which has *TextField*, when loading screen is created it launches new Thread. That thread has 3 things to do, 1) Create new object to scanning class and run it's scanning method 2)in scanning method were it gets tricky it should update status with *setStatus* and latter call method updateWidget but it returns "*android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference*" and 3) return all packages using setPackages. So how can I reach widget from thread, also extra question about part 3 which I mentioned is that right way to do ?

```
public class LoadingScreen extends Activity  {
private String status="";
List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.loadingscreen_layout);
    updateWidget();

    try {
        startLoadingScreen();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Scanner","Scanner",e);
    }

}

public void startLoadingScreen(){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner();
            setPackages(scanner.Scan());
            changeIntent();
            finish();

        }
    });

}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
void updateWidget(){
    TextView scanStatus  =  findViewById(R.id.statusView);
    scanStatus.setText(status);
}
private void changeIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayClass.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void setPackages(List<ApplicationInfo> packages) {
    this.packages = packages;
}

}
```

Scanning Class

```
public class Scanner extends Activity{
private LoadingScreen loadingScreen = new LoadingScreen();
List <android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo> Scan(){
    loadingScreen.setStatus("Scanning");
    loadingScreen.updateWidget();
    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    //get a list of installed apps.
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    return packages;

}

}
```

Comment: You can use Handler to change a value in Main Thread. Alternatively, you can also use Interfaces or LocalBroadcastManager.

Comment: you can `broadcast` from thread and in `onReceive` update the `textView`

Answer (score 0):

In your new thread `run()` method you can try to update ui by using `runOnUiThread`

```
try {
    Activity_name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
           public void run() {
                            //update ui views
                            btn.setText("some_text");
                        }
                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Alternatively you can use `AsyncTask` class to update ui elements from non ui thread.